# Blazor Server With Apm

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, elastic-stack, apm

I try to monitor my blazor server application with ELK stack using apm i do all the needed configuration but than when i get into kibana i cant see all the http requests made by the user
this is my program.cs

```
MigrationManager.Migrate(app.Services);
app.UseCors("cors");
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapHub<WorkflowInstanceHub>( "/elsa/hubs/workflow-instance");

    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
 
});

//app.MapBlazorHub();
//app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
//app.UseWorkflowsSignalRHubs();
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseMiddleware<ApmMiddleware>();
app.UseAllElasticApm(app.Configuration);
app.Run();
```

and this is the result i get
[image]